# Transport Listner used when ActiveMQ broker gets down

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to notify my client when ActiveMQ Broker got down for any reason. I am using Transport listner, but I am new. Please help me with the code.

Properties:

```
activemq.broker.url = failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?timeout=3000
```

Bean:-

```
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        factory.setTrustedPackages(Arrays.asList("org.orange.snmp"));
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        factory.setUserName(userName);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setTransportListener(new ActiveMQMonitor());
        return factory;
    }
```

Transport listner class:

```
@Component
public class ActiveMQMonitor implements TransportListener{
    
    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ActiveMQMonitor.class);

    @Override
    public void onCommand(Object command) {
        log.info("Producer received: " + command);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(IOException error) {
        log.error("Producer received: " + error);   
    }

    @Override
    public void transportInterupted() {
        log.error("Producer received transport interuption.");  
    }

    @Override
    public void transportResumed() {
        log.info("Producer received transport resumption.");    
    }

}
```

but loggers in ActiveMQMonitor is not working.

Comment: Did you check you logging configuration to ensure they are enabled?

Comment: Yes, I checked they are enabled, when will transportListner execute? I have not started my ActiveMQ but by client is up and it is sending messages to the ActiveMQ and it gives me this error:- ```Failed to connect to [tcp://localhost:61616] after: 1 attempt(s) with Connection refused: connect, continuing to retry.```

Answer (score 0):

The transport listener is called after a successful connection has actually been established and then some transport related event occurs such as an Openwire command arriving or a transport interruption.  Prior to this if using the failover transport there would be no events as there isn't anything for it to report until it has actually connected and them something of interest happens.